How do a transform a column through a function before inputing it in another formula without creating a new column?
I would like to quickly write a function for something I do constantly. I'm trying to sum the column H for different months without having to create a new column just to test a condition.
My situation
So if the numbers 7 through 11 are the months I want to quickly sum the positives number of the column H if the column L is in the month of the cell to the left.
I know I could do something like =sumifs(H:H;H:H;">0";First day of the month;">="&Q2; et cetera...
But that is very long to write.
I feel like there must be a quick way to transform the column L before inputting into the =sumifs().
I also wouldn't like to create a new column for it. The idea is to type it quickly.
Is there any way of doing it?
I tried:
=sumif(H:H;H:H;">0";month(L;L);Q2)
=sumif(H:H;H:H;">0";month($L$2:$L$44);Q2)
=sumif(H:H;H:H;">0";month({L;L});Q2)


Something like =SUMPRODUCT(H$2:H$10,--(H$2:H$10>0),--(MONTH(L$2:L$10)=Q2)) maybe?

As a scalar (one cell at a time) formula:
=SUM( H:H * (H:H >0) * (MONTH(L:L) = Q2) )
and then copy it down.
Or to use a dynamic array to only enter the formula once you could do:
=BYROW( Q2:Q6, LAMBDA(r, SUM( H:H * (H:H >0) * (MONTH(L:L) = r))))
Either formula will be slow, you'll be better off being more selective about H and L, like:
=BYROW( Q2:Q6, LAMBDA(r, SUM( H2:H100 * (H2:H100 >0) * (MONTH(L2:L100) = r))))
This confines the formula to only totaling 100 (or whatever number you need) rows instead of a million rows.
